# python pandas No ':' found when decoding object value

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to import a .json file into a panda dataframe using p.read_json. However, when I try to runt he code, I get the following error:

> No ':' found when decoding object value

The section of code where the error is being indicated as failing is:

```py
Time_3 = datetime.datetime.now()        # Time 3
ARIC_IMP = pd.read_json(user_input_2, orient="records", encoding="ISO-8859-2")  # Get data from the ARIC JSON file
ARIC_IMP.fillna('', inplace = True)     # Replace null values with blanks

Time_4 = datetime.datetime.now()        # Time 4
```

Specifically, the code breaks on:

```py
ARIC_IMP = pd.read_json(user_input_2, orient="records", encoding="ISO-8859-2")                                      # Get data from the ARIC JSON file
```

The data being imported is 1m rows of json strings, nested in 1 large json message.

Any idea on how to resolve this message?

Comment: It sounds like your JSON is invalid. You can run it through a JSON linter to find out for sure

Comment: Looks like it is missing "EOF" at the end of the line

Comment: Please include enough of the file to reproduce the error.

Comment: Did you find the solution? Am too facing the same here